# Issue with adding price field options to admin price field

Tags: civievent

CiviCRM 5.1.2, Drupal 7.59

We're attempting to add a price field option to an admin-only price field, and we're getting this error: "You must choose "Admin" visibility..."  As you can see here (https://www.screencast.com/t/9n3VBhi9FTY ), I've clearly chosen admin.  I also tried choosing public on the off chance the logic got reversed.  (FWIW we've not been able to replicate this on the demo site; there are no error messages recorded in the log and no backtrace error was generated when I turned it on and tried again.)  The client was previously on 4.6.x; has any logic around price sets changed substantively?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try after upgrading CiviCRM to 5.2.1? It might be possible it was an issue with previous version of CiviCRM.

HTH

Pradeep

Answer (score 1):

This actually turned out to be an issue that occurred when the price set was copied - the visibility settings do not appear to have come over correctly in the copying process.  We need to do more testing on this from our end but for those who are copying price sets, you might want to confirm that your visibility settings remain as expected.  Thanks to Pradeep for responding.